# Bar chart labels in wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Learning to visualize using python so this may just be a basic solution but I plotted a bar graph using below code which works:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("drinks.csv")

data = data.head(195)

continent = data["continent"].unique()
continent_sums = data.groupby(data["continent"])["total_litres_of_pure_alcohol"].sum()

plt.bar(continent,continent_sums,color = ["Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Cyan","Blue"])
plt.xlabel("Continent",color="purple")
plt.ylabel("T_Alcohol (Litres)",color="blue")
plt.title("TBD",color="green")

plt.tight_layout(pad=-5)

plt.show()
```

[image: python output]

But then I noticed the labels (being read from file) are assigned to the wrong bar when I QA'd using the same data file in excel.

[image: excel output]

From observation, looks like excel sorts the continent labels so I think that is what I need to do in python too? What do I need to do or change to fix this little snag and ensure the bar correspondes to the correct continent from file?

The data used for this post is:

```py
df = pd.read_json( '{"country":{"0":"Afghanistan","1":"Albania","2":"Algeria","3":"Andorra","4":"Angola","5":"Antigua & Barbuda","6":"Argentina","7":"Armenia","8":"Australia","9":"Austria","10":"Azerbaijan","11":"Bahamas","12":"Bahrain","13":"Bangladesh","14":"Barbados","15":"Belarus","16":"Belgium","17":"Belize","18":"Benin","19":"Bhutan","20":"Bolivia","21":"Bosnia-Herzegovina","22":"Botswana","23":"Brazil","24":"Brunei","25":"Bulgaria","26":"Burkina Faso","27":"Burundi","28":"Cote d\'Ivoire","29":"Cabo Verde","30":"Cambodia","31":"Cameroon","32":"Canada","33":"Central African Republic","34":"Chad","35":"Chile","36":"China","37":"Colombia","38":"Comoros","39":"Congo","40":"Cook Islands","41":"Costa Rica","42":"Croatia","43":"Cuba","44":"Cyprus","45":"Czech Republic","46":"North Korea","47":"DR Congo","48":"Denmark","49":"Djibouti","50":"Dominica","51":"Dominican Republic","52":"Ecuador","53":"Egypt","54":"El Salvador","55":"Equatorial Guinea","56":"Eritrea","57":"Estonia","58":"Ethiopia","59":"Fiji","60":"Finland","61":"France","62":"Gabon","63":"Gambia","64":"Georgia","65":"Germany","66":"Ghana","67":"Greece","68":"Grenada","69":"Guatemala","70":"Guinea","71":"Guinea-Bissau","72":"Guyana","73":"Haiti","74":"Honduras","75":"Hungary","76":"Iceland","77":"India","78":"Indonesia","79":"Iran","80":"Iraq","81":"Ireland","82":"Israel","83":"Italy","84":"Jamaica","85":"Japan","86":"Jordan","87":"Kazakhstan","88":"Kenya","89":"Kiribati","90":"Kuwait","91":"Kyrgyzstan","92":"Laos","93":"Latvia","94":"Lebanon","95":"Lesotho","96":"Liberia","97":"Libya","98":"Lithuania","99":"Luxembourg","100":"Madagascar","101":"Malawi","102":"Malaysia","103":"Maldives","104":"Mali","105":"Malta","106":"Marshall Islands","107":"Mauritania","108":"Mauritius","109":"Mexico","110":"Micronesia","111":"Monaco","112":"Mongolia","113":"Montenegro","114":"Morocco","115":"Mozambique","116":"Myanmar","117":"Namibia","118":"Nauru","119":"Nepal","120":"Netherlands","121":"New Zealand","122":"Nicaragua","123":"Niger","124":"Nigeria","125":"Niue","126":"Norway","127":"Oman","128":"Pakistan","129":"Palau","130":"Panama","131":"Papua New Guinea","132":"Paraguay","133":"Peru","134":"Philippines","135":"Poland","136":"Portugal","137":"Qatar","138":"South Korea","139":"Moldova","140":"Romania","141":"Russian Federation","142":"Rwanda","143":"St. Kitts & Nevis","144":"St. Lucia","145":"St. Vincent & the Grenadines","146":"Samoa","147":"San Marino","148":"Sao Tome & Principe","149":"Saudi Arabia","150":"Senegal","151":"Serbia","152":"Seychelles","153":"Sierra Leone","154":"Singapore","155":"Slovakia","156":"Slovenia","157":"Solomon Islands","158":"Somalia","159":"South Africa","160":"Spain","161":"Sri Lanka","162":"Sudan","163":"Suriname","164":"Swaziland","165":"Sweden","166":"Switzerland","167":"Syria","168":"Tajikistan","169":"Thailand","170":"Macedonia","171":"Timor-Leste","172":"Togo","173":"Tonga","174":"Trinidad & Tobago","175":"Tunisia","176":"Turkey","177":"Turkmenistan","178":"Tuvalu","179":"Uganda","180":"Ukraine","181":"United Arab Emirates","182":"United Kingdom","183":"Tanzania","184":"USA","185":"Uruguay","186":"Uzbekistan","187":"Vanuatu","188":"Venezuela","189":"Vietnam","190":"Yemen","191":"Zambia","192":"Zimbabwe"},"beer_servings":{"0":0,"1":89,"2":25,"3":245,"4":217,"5":102,"6":193,"7":21,"8":261,"9":279,"10":21,"11":122,"12":42,"13":0,"14":143,"15":142,"16":295,"17":263,"18":34,"19":23,"20":167,"21":76,"22":173,"23":245,"24":31,"25":231,"26":25,"27":88,"28":37,"29":144,"30":57,"31":147,"32":240,"33":17,"34":15,"35":130,"36":79,"37":159,"38":1,"39":76,"40":0,"41":149,"42":230,"43":93,"44":192,"45":361,"46":0,"47":32,"48":224,"49":15,"50":52,"51":193,"52":162,"53":6,"54":52,"55":92,"56":18,"57":224,"58":20,"59":77,"60":263,"61":127,"62":347,"63":8,"64":52,"65":346,"66":31,"67":133,"68":199,"69":53,"70":9,"71":28,"72":93,"73":1,"74":69,"75":234,"76":233,"77":9,"78":5,"79":0,"80":9,"81":313,"82":63,"83":85,"84":82,"85":77,"86":6,"87":124,"88":58,"89":21,"90":0,"91":31,"92":62,"93":281,"94":20,"95":82,"96":19,"97":0,"98":343,"99":236,"100":26,"101":8,"102":13,"103":0,"104":5,"105":149,"106":0,"107":0,"108":98,"109":238,"110":62,"111":0,"112":77,"113":31,"114":12,"115":47,"116":5,"117":376,"118":49,"119":5,"120":251,"121":203,"122":78,"123":3,"124":42,"125":188,"126":169,"127":22,"128":0,"129":306,"130":285,"131":44,"132":213,"133":163,"134":71,"135":343,"136":194,"137":1,"138":140,"139":109,"140":297,"141":247,"142":43,"143":194,"144":171,"145":120,"146":105,"147":0,"148":56,"149":0,"150":9,"151":283,"152":157,"153":25,"154":60,"155":196,"156":270,"157":56,"158":0,"159":225,"160":284,"161":16,"162":8,"163":128,"164":90,"165":152,"166":185,"167":5,"168":2,"169":99,"170":106,"171":1,"172":36,"173":36,"174":197,"175":51,"176":51,"177":19,"178":6,"179":45,"180":206,"181":16,"182":219,"183":36,"184":249,"185":115,"186":25,"187":21,"188":333,"189":111,"190":6,"191":32,"192":64},"spirit_servings":{"0":0,"1":132,"2":0,"3":138,"4":57,"5":128,"6":25,"7":179,"8":72,"9":75,"10":46,"11":176,"12":63,"13":0,"14":173,"15":373,"16":84,"17":114,"18":4,"19":0,"20":41,"21":173,"22":35,"23":145,"24":2,"25":252,"26":7,"27":0,"28":1,"29":56,"30":65,"31":1,"32":122,"33":2,"34":1,"35":124,"36":192,"37":76,"38":3,"39":1,"40":254,"41":87,"42":87,"43":137,"44":154,"45":170,"46":0,"47":3,"48":81,"49":44,"50":286,"51":147,"52":74,"53":4,"54":69,"55":0,"56":0,"57":194,"58":3,"59":35,"60":133,"61":151,"62":98,"63":0,"64":100,"65":117,"66":3,"67":112,"68":438,"69":69,"70":0,"71":31,"72":302,"73":326,"74":98,"75":215,"76":61,"77":114,"78":1,"79":0,"80":3,"81":118,"82":69,"83":42,"84":97,"85":202,"86":21,"87":246,"88":22,"89":34,"90":0,"91":97,"92":0,"93":216,"94":55,"95":29,"96":152,"97":0,"98":244,"99":133,"100":15,"101":11,"102":4,"103":0,"104":1,"105":100,"106":0,"107":0,"108":31,"109":68,"110":50,"111":0,"112":189,"113":114,"114":6,"115":18,"116":1,"117":3,"118":0,"119":6,"120":88,"121":79,"122":118,"123":2,"124":5,"125":200,"126":71,"127":16,"128":0,"129":63,"130":104,"131":39,"132":117,"133":160,"134":186,"135":215,"136":67,"137":42,"138":16,"139":226,"140":122,"141":326,"142":2,"143":205,"144":315,"145":221,"146":18,"147":0,"148":38,"149":5,"150":1,"151":131,"152":25,"153":3,"154":12,"155":293,"156":51,"157":11,"158":0,"159":76,"160":157,"161":104,"162":13,"163":178,"164":2,"165":60,"166":100,"167":35,"168":15,"169":258,"170":27,"171":1,"172":2,"173":21,"174":156,"175":3,"176":22,"177":71,"178":41,"179":9,"180":237,"181":135,"182":126,"183":6,"184":158,"185":35,"186":101,"187":18,"188":100,"189":2,"190":0,"191":19,"192":18},"wine_servings":{"0":0,"1":54,"2":14,"3":312,"4":45,"5":45,"6":221,"7":11,"8":212,"9":191,"10":5,"11":51,"12":7,"13":0,"14":36,"15":42,"16":212,"17":8,"18":13,"19":0,"20":8,"21":8,"22":35,"23":16,"24":1,"25":94,"26":7,"27":0,"28":7,"29":16,"30":1,"31":4,"32":100,"33":1,"34":1,"35":172,"36":8,"37":3,"38":1,"39":9,"40":74,"41":11,"42":254,"43":5,"44":113,"45":134,"46":0,"47":1,"48":278,"49":3,"50":26,"51":9,"52":3,"53":1,"54":2,"55":233,"56":0,"57":59,"58":0,"59":1,"60":97,"61":370,"62":59,"63":1,"64":149,"65":175,"66":10,"67":218,"68":28,"69":2,"70":2,"71":21,"72":1,"73":1,"74":2,"75":185,"76":78,"77":0,"78":0,"79":0,"80":0,"81":165,"82":9,"83":237,"84":9,"85":16,"86":1,"87":12,"88":2,"89":1,"90":0,"91":6,"92":123,"93":62,"94":31,"95":0,"96":2,"97":0,"98":56,"99":271,"100":4,"101":1,"102":0,"103":0,"104":1,"105":120,"106":0,"107":0,"108":18,"109":5,"110":18,"111":0,"112":8,"113":128,"114":10,"115":5,"116":0,"117":1,"118":8,"119":0,"120":190,"121":175,"122":1,"123":1,"124":2,"125":7,"126":129,"127":1,"128":0,"129":23,"130":18,"131":1,"132":74,"133":21,"134":1,"135":56,"136":339,"137":7,"138":9,"139":18,"140":167,"141":73,"142":0,"143":32,"144":71,"145":11,"146":24,"147":0,"148":140,"149":0,"150":7,"151":127,"152":51,"153":2,"154":11,"155":116,"156":276,"157":1,"158":0,"159":81,"160":112,"161":0,"162":0,"163":7,"164":2,"165":186,"166":280,"167":16,"168":0,"169":1,"170":86,"171":4,"172":19,"173":5,"174":7,"175":20,"176":7,"177":32,"178":9,"179":0,"180":45,"181":5,"182":195,"183":1,"184":84,"185":220,"186":8,"187":11,"188":3,"189":1,"190":0,"191":4,"192":4},"total_litres_of_pure_alcohol":{"0":0.0,"1":4.9,"2":0.7,"3":12.4,"4":5.9,"5":4.9,"6":8.3,"7":3.8,"8":10.4,"9":9.7,"10":1.3,"11":6.3,"12":2.0,"13":0.0,"14":6.3,"15":14.4,"16":10.5,"17":6.8,"18":1.1,"19":0.4,"20":3.8,"21":4.6,"22":5.4,"23":7.2,"24":0.6,"25":10.3,"26":4.3,"27":6.3,"28":4.0,"29":4.0,"30":2.2,"31":5.8,"32":8.2,"33":1.8,"34":0.4,"35":7.6,"36":5.0,"37":4.2,"38":0.1,"39":1.7,"40":5.9,"41":4.4,"42":10.2,"43":4.2,"44":8.2,"45":11.8,"46":0.0,"47":2.3,"48":10.4,"49":1.1,"50":6.6,"51":6.2,"52":4.2,"53":0.2,"54":2.2,"55":5.8,"56":0.5,"57":9.5,"58":0.7,"59":2.0,"60":10.0,"61":11.8,"62":8.9,"63":2.4,"64":5.4,"65":11.3,"66":1.8,"67":8.3,"68":11.9,"69":2.2,"70":0.2,"71":2.5,"72":7.1,"73":5.9,"74":3.0,"75":11.3,"76":6.6,"77":2.2,"78":0.1,"79":0.0,"80":0.2,"81":11.4,"82":2.5,"83":6.5,"84":3.4,"85":7.0,"86":0.5,"87":6.8,"88":1.8,"89":1.0,"90":0.0,"91":2.4,"92":6.2,"93":10.5,"94":1.9,"95":2.8,"96":3.1,"97":0.0,"98":12.9,"99":11.4,"100":0.8,"101":1.5,"102":0.3,"103":0.0,"104":0.6,"105":6.6,"106":0.0,"107":0.0,"108":2.6,"109":5.5,"110":2.3,"111":0.0,"112":4.9,"113":4.9,"114":0.5,"115":1.3,"116":0.1,"117":6.8,"118":1.0,"119":0.2,"120":9.4,"121":9.3,"122":3.5,"123":0.1,"124":9.1,"125":7.0,"126":6.7,"127":0.7,"128":0.0,"129":6.9,"130":7.2,"131":1.5,"132":7.3,"133":6.1,"134":4.6,"135":10.9,"136":11.0,"137":0.9,"138":9.8,"139":6.3,"140":10.4,"141":11.5,"142":6.8,"143":7.7,"144":10.1,"145":6.3,"146":2.6,"147":0.0,"148":4.2,"149":0.1,"150":0.3,"151":9.6,"152":4.1,"153":6.7,"154":1.5,"155":11.4,"156":10.6,"157":1.2,"158":0.0,"159":8.2,"160":10.0,"161":2.2,"162":1.7,"163":5.6,"164":4.7,"165":7.2,"166":10.2,"167":1.0,"168":0.3,"169":6.4,"170":3.9,"171":0.1,"172":1.3,"173":1.1,"174":6.4,"175":1.3,"176":1.4,"177":2.2,"178":1.0,"179":8.3,"180":8.9,"181":2.8,"182":10.4,"183":5.7,"184":8.7,"185":6.6,"186":2.4,"187":0.9,"188":7.7,"189":2.0,"190":0.1,"191":2.5,"192":4.7},"continent":{"0":"Asia","1":"Europe","2":"Africa","3":"Europe","4":"Africa","5":"North America","6":"South America","7":"Europe","8":"Oceania","9":"Europe","10":"Europe","11":"North America","12":"Asia","13":"Asia","14":"North America","15":"Europe","16":"Europe","17":"North America","18":"Africa","19":"Asia","20":"South America","21":"Europe","22":"Africa","23":"South America","24":"Asia","25":"Europe","26":"Africa","27":"Africa","28":"Africa","29":"Africa","30":"Asia","31":"Africa","32":"North America","33":"Africa","34":"Africa","35":"South America","36":"Asia","37":"South America","38":"Africa","39":"Africa","40":"Oceania","41":"North America","42":"Europe","43":"North America","44":"Europe","45":"Europe","46":"Asia","47":"Africa","48":"Europe","49":"Africa","50":"North America","51":"North America","52":"South America","53":"Africa","54":"North America","55":"Africa","56":"Africa","57":"Europe","58":"Africa","59":"Oceania","60":"Europe","61":"Europe","62":"Africa","63":"Africa","64":"Europe","65":"Europe","66":"Africa","67":"Europe","68":"North America","69":"North America","70":"Africa","71":"Africa","72":"South America","73":"North America","74":"North America","75":"Europe","76":"Europe","77":"Asia","78":"Asia","79":"Asia","80":"Asia","81":"Europe","82":"Asia","83":"Europe","84":"North America","85":"Asia","86":"Asia","87":"Asia","88":"Africa","89":"Oceania","90":"Asia","91":"Asia","92":"Asia","93":"Europe","94":"Asia","95":"Africa","96":"Africa","97":"Africa","98":"Europe","99":"Europe","100":"Africa","101":"Africa","102":"Asia","103":"Asia","104":"Africa","105":"Europe","106":"Oceania","107":"Africa","108":"Africa","109":"North America","110":"Oceania","111":"Europe","112":"Asia","113":"Europe","114":"Africa","115":"Africa","116":"Asia","117":"Africa","118":"Oceania","119":"Asia","120":"Europe","121":"Oceania","122":"North America","123":"Africa","124":"Africa","125":"Oceania","126":"Europe","127":"Asia","128":"Asia","129":"Oceania","130":"North America","131":"Oceania","132":"South America","133":"South America","134":"Asia","135":"Europe","136":"Europe","137":"Asia","138":"Asia","139":"Europe","140":"Europe","141":"Asia","142":"Africa","143":"North America","144":"North America","145":"North America","146":"Oceania","147":"Europe","148":"Africa","149":"Asia","150":"Africa","151":"Europe","152":"Africa","153":"Africa","154":"Asia","155":"Europe","156":"Europe","157":"Oceania","158":"Africa","159":"Africa","160":"Europe","161":"Asia","162":"Africa","163":"South America","164":"Africa","165":"Europe","166":"Europe","167":"Asia","168":"Asia","169":"Asia","170":"Europe","171":"Asia","172":"Africa","173":"Oceania","174":"North America","175":"Africa","176":"Asia","177":"Asia","178":"Oceania","179":"Africa","180":"Europe","181":"Asia","182":"Europe","183":"Africa","184":"North America","185":"South America","186":"Asia","187":"Oceania","188":"South America","189":"Asia","190":"Asia","191":"Africa","192":"Africa"}}')
```

Comment: where is the `drinks.csv` data from?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/justmarkham/alcohol-consumption-by-country @baxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `sort=False` to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for avoid sorting:

```
continent_sums = data.groupby(data["continent"], sort=False)["total_litres_of_pure_alcohol"].sum()
```